# Static XML parsing method in Web Service hauling too much memory?

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

I have a web service that makes a web request to get an XML, parses it into a custom class and returns that class. As my first choice I made a helper "XMLParser" class with the needed parsing methods, and made the methods static since I didn't see a need to instantiate and XMLParser class. But then I started wondering if this was consuming more memory than what it should. Suggestions?

**EDIT**

As requested, some code. I've simplified the code to get straight to the point.

The WebMethod being called

```
[WebMethod]
public List<CustomObject> GetObjectList(int xmlID)
{
    string xmlURL = URLBuilder.GetXmlURL(xmlID); // Also static method that builds and returns an URL
    HttpWebRequest xmlRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(xmlURL);
    xmlRequest.Method = "GET";

    try
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = xmlRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            XmlDocument XML = new XmlDocument();
            XML.Load(responseStream);

            return XMLParser.GetCustomObjectList(XML);
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

And the static method I'm worried about

```
public static List<CustomObject> GetCustomObjectList(XmlDocument XML)
{
    XmlNodeList nodesList = XML.GetElementsByTagName("some_tag");
    List<CustomObject> obj = new List<CustomObject>();

    foreach (XmlNode listingNode in listingNodesList)
    {
        // Read Nodes and add CustomObjects to the obj List
    }

    return obj;
}
```

This will be parsing XMLs constantly and returning Lists of CustomObject. By any change on each parse, memory is allocated and never freed?

Comment: What do you think consumes more memory than it should? The fact that you are using static methods? If yes, my suggestion is to not think about it. If no, could you clarify your question?

Comment: What I think it's consuming memory is the fact that a static method is parsing all the XMLs retrieved. That memory could be staking up and after a few XMLs are the memory consumed is more than what it should.

Comment: I think you would have to show some code. Just using static methods won't cost you any more memory per se. It's a matter of how they are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem too. When I'm writing the StreamReader response from HttpWebResponse to some string it allocates lots of memory (for about 100'000 line xml in response it reaches 800 MB). Actual data is not so large and I have no idea what to do.

I do not use static class nor method. What I see in debug is that "huge" allocation happens on one particular response and deallocation depends on garbage collection logic (IMHO).

Now I try to divide the data somehow. If I have some results I'll update this post.

(Sorry for unclear answer, I couldn't add it as comment)